# How can I indicate the PathVariable for Spring REST-method?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to indicate the pathvariable secondpart. Thats not possible because an errormessage shows: Could not determine type for: veranstaltung.Identificationnumber, at table: teilnehmer, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(id)]

What I have to change to use the variable secondpart? How can I access the variable secondpart in the method of the Controller?

```
    package veranstaltung;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Teilnehmer {


static int idnumber=69;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Identificationnumber id;
private String name;
private String vorname;
private String wohnort;

protected Teilnehmer() {}

public Teilnehmer(Identificationnumber id, String name, String vorname,String wohnort)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.vorname=vorname;
    this.wohnort=wohnort;
}


public static String erzeugeID ()
{
    String id= "JAVALAND-";
    id=id+idnumber;
    idnumber++;
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getVorname() {
    return vorname;
}

public void setVorname(String vorname) {
    this.vorname = vorname;
}

public String getWohnort() {
    return wohnort;
}

public void setWohnort(String wohnort) {
    this.wohnort = wohnort;
}


@Override
public String toString()
{
    return  id.getfullID()+" "+getName()+" "+getVorname()+" "+getWohnort();
}
```

}

```
    package veranstaltung;

public class Identificationnumber {


private String firstpart;
private Long secondpart;

public Identificationnumber(String firstpart, Long secondpart)
{
    this.firstpart=firstpart;
    this.secondpart=secondpart;
}


public String getFirstpart() {
    return firstpart;
}

public void setFirstpart(String firstpart) {
    this.firstpart = firstpart;
}

public Long getSecondpart() {
    return secondpart;
}

public void setSecondpart(Long secondpart) {
    this.secondpart = secondpart;
}

public String getfullID()
{
    return firstpart+' '+secondpart;
}
```

}

```
    package veranstaltung;

import veranstaltung.Teilnehmer;
import veranstaltung.Identificationnumber;
import veranstaltung.TeilnehmerRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class TeilnehmerController {

@Autowired
TeilnehmerRepository teilnehmerRepository;


@GetMapping("/teilnehmer")
    Iterable<Teilnehmer> teilnehmer(){
        return this.teilnehmerRepository.findAll();
    }

@GetMapping("/teilnehmer/{id}")
Teilnehmer teilnehmerById(@PathVariable Long secondpart){
    Optional<Teilnehmer> teilnehmerOptional = this.teilnehmerRepository.findById(secondpart);
    if(teilnehmerOptional.isPresent()) {
        return teilnehmerOptional.get();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: The entity should use a String for the id, you can use the getfullId method when you construct it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Identificationnumber` is not primitive but custom class. What you are doing is trying to use `Long` against your `Identificationnumber` in `teilnehmerById` method.

I would suggest to either change `@Id` column of  `Teilnehmer` to `Long` from  `Identificationnumber` or you can still pass `Identificationnumber` in `teilnehmerById` method by doing something like below (This is based on consideration that you have implemented your own `findById` which will convert `Identificationnumber` to `Long`):

```
@GetMapping("/teilnehmer/{id}")
Teilnehmer teilnehmerById(@PathVariable Long secondpart){
     Identificationnumber number = new Identificationnumber();
     number.setSecondpart(secondpart);
   
  
    Optional<Teilnehmer> teilnehmerOptional = this.teilnehmerRepository.findById(number.getfullID());
    if(teilnehmerOptional.isPresent()) {
        return teilnehmerOptional.get();
    }
    return null;
```

Based on hibernate error, it looks like you have to use my first option which is change `@Id` of `Teilnehmer` to `Long`.

Edit : just updated code so that you can use composition of String to Long.

Comment: I can not change the id of Teilnehmer to Long.

Comment: Actually I need the composition of String and Long.

Comment: Well, in that case, can you try using my second option & let me know error if there is any.

Comment: @EricWinter, edited my code to fulfil your requirement.